# Finding all possible permutations/combinations to equal a specific sum in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, combinations

I was asked to solve this simple problem, and my skill in programming is quite miserable. Here it is,

Given the following items, find all the combinations of clothing items so that the total cost is exactly $100.

Here is my code:

```
tshirt=20; %price of tshirt
shorts=15; %price of shorts
socks=5; %price of socks 
solution=0;


 for i=20 %cannot have more than 20 socks (over $100)
    for j = 6 %cannot have more than 6 shorts (over $100)%cannot have more than 20 socks (over $100)
        for k=5 %cannot have more 5 tshirts (over $100)

        %Some code or function that will add them up so they are
        %exactly $100??

        tshirt+shorts+socks==100
        end
     end
 end
```

I know this code is primitive, but I am clueless on how to approach....
Any assistance will be much appreciated.

Comment: This is basically the coin change problem, it'll be a good start to search for that.

Comment: The final equation should look like i * tshirt+j * shorts+k * socks==100. I do not remember Matlab but generally you should have: if (i * tshirt+j * shorts+k * socks==100) solution=solution+1

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have a good start on this problem, and I can see that the you're struggling with the code a bit.  I'll try to help you out.

```
tshirt=20; %price of tshirt
shorts=15; %price of shorts
socks=5; %price of socks 
solution=0;
```

Good start, we know the prices of things.  Looks like the issue is in the for loops though, you want to go through all of the possibilities...

```
for i = 0:20
  for j = 0:6
    for k = 0:5
      %Check to see if this combonation is equal to 100 bucks
      if(i*socks + j*shorts + k*tshirt == 100)
        %I'll let you figure out the rest ;)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Hope that can get you started.  what a for loop actually does is sets that variable to all of the things between the numbers you supply inclusive, increment by 1.  This way, i = 0, then 1, then 2... etc...  So now you can check each combination.

Answer (score 1):

You can also populate a 3-D matrix with all the possible values of the sums as your ranges are pretty small ; Then, you just look for the values that are equal too `100` :

```
price=100;

tshirt=20; %price of tshirt
shorts=15; %price of shorts
socks=5; %price of socks 

[X,Y,Z]=meshgrid(1:floor(100/tshirt),1:floor(100/shorts),1:floor(100/socks));
SumsMatrix=tshirt*X+shorts*Y+socks*Z;

linIds=find(SumsMatrix==100);
[idx,idy,idz]=ind2sub(size(SumsMatrix),linIds);

comb=[idx idy idz]
```